# Solve this equation $\binom{4}{x}^2-\binom{4}{x}-25=0$

Tags: calculus, number-theory, gamma-function

Can I solve this equation $$\binom{4}{x}^2-\binom{4}{x}-25=0$$

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be integer?

Comment: not necessary to be integer

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Isn't the choose function supposed to be $n\choose k$ such that $n$ and $k$ are non-negative integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solve $u^2 - u - 25 = 0$, you get $u=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{101}}{2}$. Now solve ${4 \choose x} = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{101}}{2}$. In terms of integers this has no solutions. If you use an interpolation of the binomial coefficient, then you may have some solutions. The usual such interpolation comes from replacing each instance of $x!$ in the formula with $\Gamma(x+1)$.

Comment: Since he beat me to it, you'll be searching for two answers. About $1.5$ and about $2.5$

Comment: Thus there is no solution. Binomial coefficient is defined in terms of factorials, and factorials are defined for integers and a range in the integers. Binomial coefficients are always positive integers.  If you have to substitute the gamma function to solve it then its not the same original equation. Results are superfluous.  Youre only introducing solutions by substituting out the function for something else entirely.

Comment: Yes, I just realized this! I jumped to conclusions before I actually used my brain to consider the limitations of the choose function.

Comment: I would point out that the gamma function is only one of many different functions that interpolates and extrapolates on the factorial. Im always a bit put off when people assume a continuous analogue **has** to be the gamma.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Quite true. Still, it's what's usually meant without additional clarification.

Comment: That mentality lacks rigor. Its an assumption without any backing, nothing more significant than that.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Yep. But given that there's a gamma-function tag here, I think there actually is some backing.

Comment: You cant be serious? Just because one student who doesnt know how to solve a problem, and who arguably doesnt know what he is doing, puts a tag on a webpage you think you are *mathematically* justified in making this substitution? If this were permissible in the askers book, he would have said as much explicitly.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum You're still ultimately wrong in this case if you look at the comment under the OP: he's explicitly not requiring $x$ to be an integer, has presented an equation with no integer solutions, and has included a gamma-function tag, so unless he says otherwise, I think it is fair to conclude that he wants the answer provided by the gamma function. Nevertheless I've added in some explicit remarks to this effect.